# android facebook sdk 3.0 login and get user info

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm developing an APP which using needs few facebook info to register my own website.

At first I was using facebook SDK 1.5, everything is working well. Until facebook says they'll stop supporting old(v2.0 and below) SDK since June 2013.

So I have to upgrade it to 3.0, and re-write my code.

Here's what I have done so far after read about facebook's official tutorial :

manifst.xml

```
<!-- some stuff -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fbAppId"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

strings.xml

```
<!-- some stuff -->
<string name="fbAppId">1234567890</string> <!-- You do know this ID is fake, right ? -->
```

code

```
public class LoginFragment extends SherlockFragment
{
  private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

  private Session.StatusCallback callback=new Session.StatusCallback()
  {
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception)
    {
      onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
  };

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "user_status", "email"));

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper=new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session=Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session!=null&&(session.isOpened()||session.isClosed()))
    {
      onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
  {
    try
    {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      setUserVisibleHint(true);
      uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Error on save instance state, "+e.toString());
    }
  }

  private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
  {
    if(state.isOpened()) //I don't know why state is always not opened......?
    {
      Request request=Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
      {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
        {
          if(user!=null)
          {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Logged in...");
            Log.d("user fname", user.getFirstName());
            Log.d("user lname", user.getLastName());
            Log.d("user username", user.getUsername());
            Log.d("user email", (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email"));
          }
          else
          {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Logged out...");
          }

        }
      });

      Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my APP, I can see a facebook login button.

Press it, a dialog will shows up to ask me to allow my APP to access facebook info, email...etc.

And after I press Yes, there is nothing happen, nothing comes out even in LogCat...

How do I know user are actually logged in facebook, and access their info ?

Comment: You should try to print out any exceptions in your callback's call() method.

Comment: Thanks, I add this in call() :   Log.w(Constants.TAG, "Exception: "+String.valueOf(exception==null)); .............. But ths exception is null.

Comment: Can you also print out the SessionState for each callback, and see which states it's transitioning through (and that the onActivityResult method is actually being called for your app)? Also, do you perhaps have "destroy activities immediately" turned on as a debug setting on your device?

Answer (score 0):

you should override onActivityResult method and call

```
authButton.onActivityResult(params);
```

Comment: Thanks, I add this "authButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);" in override onActivityResult, but still nothing happen...

Comment: Hey @Cromir I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Why would this be happening?